how to get an token account's Mint address on chain?
In my anchor program, I declare a uncheck account that will check by code inside instruction function
    /// CHECK: do check inside function.
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_ata:  UncheckedAccount<'info>,

and inside the functuon, I don't know how to get the mint property of user_ata account
  msg!("check user-ata owner: {:?}, user: {:?} ", user_ata_info.owner, ctx.accounts.user.key());

  if *user_ata_info.owner != *ctx.accounts.user.key() {
      msg!("check user-ata owner: {:?},  user: {:?} ", user_ata_info.owner, *ctx.accounts.user.key());
      panic!("user-ata account's owner member do not match with accounts.user key ");
  }
  
  // ? how to get mint property from 'user_ata_info' ? 

Thanks

If you are use a typed Anchor TokenAccount, you can do so directly because anchor deserializes the account when the ix is called.
use anchor_spl::{
    token::{Mint, Token, TokenAccount},
};

#[account(mut)]
pub user_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

let mint = ctx.accounts.user_ata.mint;

If using an unchecked account
use anchor_spl::{
    token::{Mint, Token, TokenAccount},
};

let data = ctx.accounts.user_ata.data.try_borrow_mut().unwrap();
let data = TokenAccount::try_deserialize(&mut data.as_ref());

if let Ok(token_account) = data {
    let mint = token_account.mint;
} else {
    // panic or handle err
}


It work! It is too kind of you.
